# Can Google Sheet's =AVERAGE function count multiple values only once?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, is it possible to count multiple values inside the `=AVERAGE` function only once?

**Example:**

```
=AVERAGE(32.3,48.9,33.2,48.9,33.5,49,33.8,49,33.5,48.5,48.8,33.9)
```

Count **33.5** only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`=UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) for this, to remove duplicate values from a list of numbers. Note that `=UNIQUE` takes an *array* as parameter, not a list of numbers, so we need to wrap your list of numbers in [`{}`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en):

```
=UNIQUE({32.3; 48.9; 33.2; 48.9; 33.5; 49; 33.8; 49; 33.5; 48.5; 48.8; 33.9})
```

This gives you a list of 9 elements - the duplicates have been removed:

```
32.3, 48.9, 33.2, 33.5, 49, 33.8, 48.5, 48.8, 33.9
```

---

Knowing this, we can combine the two formulas:

```
=AVERAGE(UNIQUE({32.3; 48.9; 33.2; 48.9; 33.5; 49; 33.8; 49; 33.5; 48.5; 48.8; 33.9}))
```

which gives the expected result of `40.21111111`.

---

I have created [a spreadsheet to demonstrate this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UxIZ7BsWuh1MewzlwgnW8xlZj4UAr6unxIbBMhDaTL0/edit?usp=sharing), feel free to copy it.
And see the documentation for [`=UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en), [`=AVERAGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615?hl=en) and [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en).